# Signalling a particular thread among many waiting on a condition variable

Tags: c, linux, condition-variable

This question follows from [Breaking a condition variable deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907083/breaking-a-condition-variable-deadlock/6907121#6907121). A number of threads may be waiting on a condition variable, I need to signal only a particular thread say thread 1 and kill it as it was a participant of a deadlock scenario. Is there a way i could signal just a partipular thread amoung the lot.

Would be gratefull for some help

thanks

An Edit; Respecting Nemo's comments. I understand this is a bad idea. But, is there a way to do it

Comment: With probability very close to 1, your design is flawed.  You almost certainly do _not_ want to "detect deadlock and kill one of the threads participating in it".  You want to fix your basic design so that deadlock never happens...

Comment: @Nemo... I agree with you. But, in our particuar case we choose to detect and resolve deadlock rather then avoiding it because the probability of deadlock occurence is extremely rare.

Comment: Sorry @Juggler, but I do not buy that philosophy.  This is software.  There is no such thing as "extremely rare".  There is only "never" and "buggy".  Or as Yoda would say, there is no try.

Comment: @Nemo, Well, if you're writing, say, a database transaction system, where the contents of the transaction are provided by higher level code, it may be reasonable to abort the transaction and retry on deadlock (Berkeley DB does this, as do many SQL implementations). So I wouldn't say this is never a reasonable approach. It's just _rarely_ a reasonable approach - particularly since you must have a rollback plan for when you cancel the offending thread

Comment: @bdonlan...yes. I should have probably said the context before but don't know why I did not. Well the project here is an experimental file system that provides transactions

Answer (score 1):

You can use deferred cancellation points. In your threads, use `pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, &oldstate);` (this is the default, but it never hurts to be explicit); then disable cancellation with `pthread_setcancelstate` except for over the condition variable waits you want to be cancellable. Be sure that you use `pthread_cleanup_push` to set up cancellation cleanup handlers; this will NOT play nicely with RAII.

And now you can just pthread_cancel your thread. Cancellation cleanup handlers are executed, in reverse order of registration, TLS data destructors are called, and the thread exits (without returning from the condition variable wait).

Of course, this is a rather ugly design. Ideally you should avoid deadlocking at all; if that isn't possible, if it were me, I would arrange for only one thread to ever block on a single cvar at a time, and build a higher level (explicit waiter list) construct based on these cvars in order to handle multiple waiters, while still allowing for threads to be individually addressable.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit?  Is there not a fundamental race condition between enabling cancellation and waiting on the condition variable?  That is, you hold a mutex, enable cancellation, and then try to wait on the cond var...  But in the meantime somebody decides you are deadlocked and nukes you while you hold the mutex?

Comment: @Nemo, from the pthread_cond_wait manpage: "A condition wait (whether timed or not) is a cancellation point. When the cancelability enable state of a thread is set to PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, a side effect of acting upon a cancellation request while in a condition wait is that the mutex is (in effect) re-acquired before calling the first cancellation cleanup handler." So your cleanup handler must release the mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Just write code to do exactly what you need. There's no shortcut since condition variables don't provide this behavior. So just write it. There's nothing difficult about it. For example, you could set a special flag, wake all threads blocked on the condition variable, and then code the threads to check the flag to see if there's supposed to go back to sleep or not.